# Closing cover produces a Re-layout

Tags: android, android-studio

I have some problems with this log. When I close the cover of my phone it says this and my activity goes to next one when this should not happen. Is it possible to avoid this happening?? Avoid Relayout or focus changing??
It doesn't happen when in a Second phone with PIN number. (So i need to put the pin to unlock the phone).

With no PIN so, phone is not locked, just closed the cover. When I open again and the activity restart, the activity had finished and went to next one.

With the second phone, with PIN, when I close I have to put the PIN to enter again and in this case, the activity went in the normal way.

```
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@670a516[Fer_Habit]
    getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.example.gms ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : false , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=129
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 9675
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 742123461
I/ViewRootImpl@e954868[Class1]: stopped(true) old=false
D/OpenGLRenderer: makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x72a3179900 -> 0x0
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
D/OpenGLRenderer: destroyEglSurface : 0x72a3179900
I/mali_egl: eglDestroySurface() in
I/mali_winsys: delete_surface() [2960x1440] return
I/mali_egl: eglDestroySurface() out
E/OpenGLRenderer: ReliableSurface: perform returned an error
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x72e1651f50 disconnect failed
D/OpenGLRenderer: ~ReliableSurface : 0x72e1651f40
I/ViewRootImpl@e954868[Class1]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,2960,1440) new=(0,0,2960,1440) req=(2960,1440)8 dur=4 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=false
I/ViewRootImpl@e954868[Class1]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@670a516[Class1]
    getNavigationBarColor() -855310
```